# Get Items in an array that not existed in my database table?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I have a table `Products` in my database. I have an array that has some Id like

```
var ids = new[] { 10, 12, 1000, 1100 };
```

In my table product 10 and 20 do exist, while 1000, 1100 do not exist. How can I write an optimized linq query to get items that do not exist in my table? (1000, 1100)

I think the optimize query is like

```
select
    a.y
from
    (select 10 as y
     union all
     select 12 as y
     union all
     select 800 as y
     union all
     select 8000 as y) as a
where
    a.y not in (select p.Id from Products as p);
```

How can I generate a query like this with linq?

Comment: Get items which do not exist? When they do not exist, you can't get them, or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @dee I think he wants to determine which ones in the list don't exist in the table.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
var ids = new[] { 10, 12, 1000, 1100 };
var result = ids.Except(dbContext.Products.Where(p => ids.Contains(p.ID)).Select(p => p.ID)).ToList();
```

Comment: If I havemany item in my array I fetch many data from database in my application.I Update my question

Comment: @M.Azad unfortunatly I don't know any other way to do what you need. But you transfering only ID's from DB. and count of those ID will be always less or equal to ones you passed to. If you considered about data trasfered over network, with large number of ID you query will be heavy as well

Answer (score 0):

Answer

```
var ids = new[] { 10, 12, 1000, 1100 };

var result = (from p in dbContext.Products
                      where ids.Contains(p.ID)
                      select p).ToList();
```

Comment: Any additional explanation would be nice.

Comment: This only get what existed in ids